# How to get image from webpage

Tags: python, image, github, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am editing a Python script which gets images from a webpage (which needs a private login, so there is no point in me posting a link to it). It uses the BeautifulSoup library, and the original script is [here](https://github.com/nateberman/Python-WebImageScraper).

What I would like to do is to customize this script to get a single image, the HTML tag of which has the id attribute `id="fimage"`. It has no class. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from urllib.request import urlopen

# use this image scraper from the location that 
#you want to save scraped images to

def make_soup(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    return BeautifulSoup(html)

def get_images(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    #this makes a list of bs4 element tags
    images = [img for img in soup.find(id="fimage")]
    print (images)
    print (str(len(images)) + " images found.")
    # print 'Downloading images to current working directory.'
    #compile our unicode list of image links
    image_links = [each.get('src') for each in images]
    for each in image_links:
        filename=each.split('/')[-1]
        urlretrieve(each, filename)
    return image_links


get_images('http://myurl');


#a standard call looks like this
#get_images('http://www.wookmark.com')
```

For some reason, this doesn't seem to work. When run on the command line, it produces the output:

```
[]
0 images found.
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay so I have changed the code and now the script seems to find the image I'm trying to download, but it throws another error when run and can't download it.

Here is the updated code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from urllib.request import urlopen

def make_soup(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    return BeautifulSoup(html)

def get_images(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    #this makes a list of bs4 element tags

    image = soup.find(id="logo", src=True)
    if image is None:
        print('No images found.')
        return

    image_link = image['src']
    filename = image_link.split('/')[-1]
    request.urlretrieve(filename)
    return image_link
try:    
    get_images('https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ClientForm/0.2.10');
except ValueError as e: 
    print("File could not be retrieved.", e)
else:
    print("It worked!")

#a standard call looks like this
#get_images('http://www.wookmark.com')
```

When run on the command line the output is:

```
File could not be retrieved. unknown url type: 'python-logo.png'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.find(id="fimage")` returns *one result*, not a list. You are trying to loop over that one element, which means it'll try and list the child nodes, and there are none.

Simply adjust your code to take into account you only have one result; remove all the looping:

```
image = soup.find(id="fimage", src=True)
if image is None:
    print('No matching image found')
    return

image_link = image['src']
filename = image_link.split('/')[-1]
urlretrieve(each, filename)
```

I refined the search a little; by adding `src=True` you only match a tag if it has a `src` attribute.

Comment: So if I changed the .find to .find_all, would this return a list? Or is the problem that I'm searching a page with only one image but programmatically searching for more than one?

Comment: @DrBrown: yes, `.find_all()` returns a list, `.find()` just one result (the first). Your problem is that you were treating that one result as a list, and that BeautifulSoup elements *can* be iterated over *too*. So `for img in image_object` *works*, but that would list the child elements of the `<img>` tag, and there never are.

Comment: I'm still getting no results. Would the fact that you have to log in to the page to see the image affect the script's ability to get it?

Comment: @DrBrown: I was assuming that you left out the code to log in on purpose. Yes, you need to log in first, that's kinda a given.